# Python Typehint Generic Collection

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, python-typing

I am wondering about the proper way to type-hint a 'collection' class in Python?

I have a collection class with an instance attribute of type 'T' to hold a collection of items:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import TypeVar, Union

@dataclass
class SurfaceTypeA:
    def common_method(self) -> None:
        pass

@dataclass
class SurfaceTypeB:
    def common_method(self) -> None:
        pass

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[SurfaceTypeA, SurfaceTypeB])

@dataclass
class SurfaceCollection[T]:

    _surfaces: list[T] = field(default_factory=list)

    def run_common_method_on_surfaces(self) -> None:
        for s in self._surfaces:
            s.common_method()
```

This runs fine, but in my IDE (VS-Code), I get a type-warning on the line `s.common_method()`:

> Cannot access member "common_method" for type "object*"

[image: Screen Shot from VS-Code]

Is there a proper way to type-hint a scenario like this so VS-Code recognizes the type?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a union bound, rather than make `T` a constrained type variable (`TypeVar('T', SurfaceTypeA, SurfaceTypeB)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing old and new syntax. You either use `TypeVar` or `class Foo[T]:` but not both. Try

```
class SurfaceCollection[T: SurfaceTypeA | SurfaceTypeB]:
```

and deleting the `TypeVar`.

Currently the `T` in `class SurfaceCollection[T]:` is shadowing the `TypeVar` and so is bound to `object` not `Union[SurfaceTypeA, SurfaceTypeB]`.